# Emulation of a DOM object

Tags: javascript, dom, ecmascript-5

Property attribute control 
+ 
accessor properties  = Able to emulate DOM api in ES5 code.

In the below code, for accessor properties,

```
var domObj = document.body;
Object.defineProperty(domObj, 'innerHTML', {
                            get: innerHTML(){return innerHTML;},
                            set: innerHTML(newHTML){innerHTML = newHTML;} 
                            });
```

console gives syntax error `missing } after property list`

Does the property list syntax has any issue?

Comment: ES5 getter/setter syntax can only be used on object literals, not to modify existing objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `function` keyword missing:

```
Object.defineProperty(domObj, 'innerHTML', {
  get: function(){return innerHTML;},
  set: function(newHTML){innerHTML = newHTML;} 
});
```

You can also use

```
Object.defineProperty(domObj, 'innerHTML', {
  get(){return innerHTML;},
  set(newHTML){innerHTML = newHTML;} 
});
```

Or arrow functions

```
Object.defineProperty(domObj, 'innerHTML', {
  get: () => innerHTML,
  set: (newHTML) => {innerHTML = newHTML;} 
});
```

```js
var innerHTML = 123,
    domObj = document.body;
Object.defineProperty(domObj, 'innerHTML', {
  get: function(){return innerHTML;},
  set: function(newHTML){innerHTML = newHTML;} 
});
snippet.log(domObj.innerHTML); // 123
domObj.innerHTML = "abc";
snippet.log(innerHTML); // "abc"
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 --><script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can't I set `configurable` to `true` before configuring it?

Comment: @overexchange `defineProperty` redefines a property completely, so if you want it to be configurable you must include `configurable: true`.

Comment: Yes I did, `Object.defineProperty(domObj, 'innerHTML', {configurable: true});` but I see `TypeError: can't redefine non-configurable property "innerHTML"`. Is it because `domObj` is sealed or frozen?

Comment: @overexchange No, you must add `configurable: true` each time you redefine the property. If you first redefine the property only with the getter and setter, it will become non-configurable and you won't be able to define it again.

Comment: With getter/setter, If I add `configurable` it gives the same error

Comment: @overexchange You must have already redefined it as non-configurable. I have added a snippet.